# Problem using SQLite :memory: with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite, orm, integration-testing

I use NHibernate for my dataacess, and for awhile not I've been using SQLite for local integration tests.  I've been using a file, but I thought I would out the :memory: option.  When I fire up any of the integration tests, the database seems to be created (NHibernate spits out the table creation sql) but interfacting with the database causes an error.

Has anyone every gotten NHibernate working with an in memory database?  Is it even possible?  The connection string I'm using is this:

```
Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True
```

Comment: There is another solution since a while. See the additional block in my answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A SQLite memory database only exists as long as the connection to it remains open.  To use it in unit tests with NHibernate:
1. Open an ISession at the beginning of your test (maybe in a [SetUp] method).
2. Use the connection from that session in your SchemaExport call.
3. Use that same session in your tests.
4. Close the session at the end of your test (maybe in a [TearDown] method).

Comment: agh, that makes perfect sense! Will give it a shot

Comment: also take a look at this exemple implementing DriverConnectionProvider:
http://notepad2.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/unit-testing-castle-active-record-using-sqlite-in-memory-database/

Comment: FYI, I had trouble keeping the connection open with NHibernate after a call to Flush. Found the answer at http://bit.ly/23CRTT

Answer (score 21):

I was able to use a SQLite in-memory database and avoid having to rebuild the schema for each test by using SQLite's [support for 'Shared Cache'](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#sharedmemdb), which allows an in-memory database to be shared across connections.

I did the following in *AssemblyInitialize* (I'm using MSTest):

- Configure NHibernate (Fluently) to use SQLite with the following connection string:

  ```
  FullUri=file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared
  ```
- Use that configuration to create a hbm2ddl.**SchemaExport** object, and execute it on a separate connection (but with that same connection string again).
- Leave that connection open, and referenced by a static field, until *AssemblyCleanup*, at which point it is closed and disposed of. This is because SQLite needs at least one active connection to be held on the in-memory database to know it's still required and avoid tidying up.

Before each test runs, a new session is created, and the test runs in a transaction which is rolled back at the end.

Here is an example of the test assembly-level code:

```
[TestClass]
public static class SampleAssemblySetup
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "FullUri=file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared";
    private static SQLiteConnection _connection;

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
        var configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                                       .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(ConnectionString))
                                       .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("MyMappingsAssembly")))
                                       .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "call"))
                                       .BuildConfiguration();

        // Create the schema in the database
        // Because it's an in-memory database, we hold this connection open until all the tests are finished
        var schemaExport = new SchemaExport(configuration);
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
        _connection.Open();
        schemaExport.Execute(false, true, false, _connection, null);
    }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void AssemblyTearDown()
    {
        if (_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
            _connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And a base class for each unit test class/fixture:

```
public class TestBase
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        NHibernateBootstrapper.InitializeSession();
        var transaction = SessionFactory.Current.GetCurrentSession().BeginTransaction();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public virtual void Cleanup()
    {
        var currentSession = SessionFactory.Current.GetCurrentSession();
        if (currentSession.Transaction != null)
        {
            currentSession.Transaction.Rollback();
            currentSession.Close();
        }

        NHibernateBootstrapper.CleanupSession();
    }
}
```

Resource management could improve, I admit, but these are unit tests after all (suggested improvements welcome!).

Comment: Perfect! This is the best solution, other solutions often are based on older versions of sqlite that did not provide the possibility to use named ("file:xyz.db?mode=memory") in-memory sqlite dbs with a connection pooling active.

Comment: Note in later versions of sqlite you may need to do something like this for your connection string (and this works with Loquacious API): `config.DataBaseIntegration(c => { /*...*/ c.ConnectionString = "DataSource=file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared" })` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12324672/489116 and comments, and https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=26312#p119530 .

Answer (score 9):

We are using SQLite in memory for all our database tests. We are using a single ADO connection for the tests that is reused for all NH sessions opened by the same test.

1. Before every test: create connection
2. Create schema on this connection
3. Run test. The same connection is used for all sessions
4. After test: close connection

This allows also running tests with several sessions included. The SessionFactory is also created once for all tests, because the reading of the mapping files takes quite some time.

---

Edit

### Use of the Shared Cache

Since System.Data.Sqlite 1.0.82 (or [Sqlite 3.7.13](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_13.html)), there is a [Shared Cache](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html), which allows several connections to share the same data, also for [In-Memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). This allows creation of the in-memory-database in one connection, and use it in another. (I didn't try it yet, but in theory, this should work):

- Change the connection string to `file::memory:?cache=shared`
- Open a connection and create the schema
- Keep this connection open until the end of the test
- Let NH create other connections (normal behavior) during the test.

Comment: Do you use the OpenSession overload to suppy the connection or do you have a more cunning way of using the same connection?

Comment: I use OpenSession(IDbConnection), and get the connection once from sessionFactory.ConnectionProvider.GetConnection(). I could probably implement my own ConnectionProvider, then it would only be a matter of configuration. But I didn't have the time to do this until now.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problems that lasted even after opening the ISession as stated above, and adding "Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1" to my connection string. It helped, but I still had some cases where the connection would close during a test (usually right after committing a transaction).

What finally worked for me was setting the property "connection.release_mode" to "on_close" in my SessionFactory configuration.

My configuration in the app.config file now look likes this:

```
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <reflection-optimizer use="true" />
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">testSqlLiteDB</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried this solution but it has a serious draw-back when using HiLo Id-Generators. When inserting a hughe amount of new database entries this solution breaks. The reason is that nhibernate can only obtain one connection but might need an additional one to get the next HiLo-Range from the DB. With newer versions of sqlite the better solution is to use the solutiuon that decates provided [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15574248/3722909).

Answer (score 1):

I hade alot off problems with SQLite memory database.
So now we are using SQLite working with files on a ramdrive disk.

Comment: This might have been a solution in the past but is unnecessary with newer versions of sqlite as they provide the ability to use a shared scope of the database. This is much easier to use and less tooling intensive. For a up-to-date solution see the following [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15574248/3722909)

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but is the sql output by NHibernate using a command unsupported by sqlite?

Also, What happens if you use a file instead of memory? (System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() would work i think...)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it with [Rhino Commons](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/rhino-commons/).  If you don't want to use Rhino Commons you can study the source do see how it does it.  The only problem I have had is that SQLite does not support nested transactions.  This forced me to change my code to support integration testing.  Integration testing with in memory database is so awesome, I decided it was a fair compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to thank decates. Been trying to solve this for a couple of months now and all I had to do was add

```
FullUri=file:memorydb.db?mode=memory&cache=shared
```

to the connection string in my nhibernate config file.  Also using just NHibernate with *.hbm.xml and not FNH and didn't really have to modify my code at all!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, when I forgot to import the SQLite Nuget package.