# Problems with HasMany, Lazy loading and session scopes

Tags: nhibernate, session, activerecord, lazy-loading, castle-activerecord

I have a console application that uses NHibernate and ActiveRecord.

I am using the following detached criteria:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ServiceOrder>();

            criteria.Add(Restrictions.Lt("End", DateTime.Today.AddDays(3)));
            criteria.Add(new Disjunction()
                            .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("StopReason"))
                            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("StopReason", ServiceStopReason.Worthiness)));

            criteria.Add(new Disjunction()
                            .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("StopDate"))
                            .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("StopDate", "End")));
```

And I am invoking the fetching using ActiveRecordMediator's FindAll() method.
In my model I have this property:

```
[HasMany(Lazy = true)]
public virtual ISet<ServiceOrder> ServiceOrders
{
    get { return serviceOrders; }
    set { serviceOrders = value; }
}
```

Which I'm trying to access to in the following Linq query:

```
from serviceOrder in serviceOrderDataService.GetServiceOrdersWithEndOfEntitlement()
     let accountGetService = serviceOrder.AccountGetService
     where accountGetService != null
     let serviceOrders = accountGetService.ServiceOrders
     where serviceOrders != null && serviceOrders.Count != 0
     let isFutureServiceOrder = (from accountGetServiceServiceOrder in serviceOrders
                                      where serviceOrder.Start.HasValue
                                      && accountGetServiceServiceOrder.End.HasValue
                                      && serviceOrder.Start > accountGetServiceServiceOrder.End
                                      select accountGetServiceServiceOrder).Any()
     where !isFutureServiceOrder
     select serviceOrder;
```

But I am getting the following exception:

> Initializing[Danel.Nursing.Model.AccountService#61786367-e8da-4929-b91b-a7497cf7db10]-failed
>   to lazily initialize a collection of
>   role:
>   Danel.Nursing.Model.AccountService.ServiceOrders,
>   no session or session was closed

Does this makes any sense? How do I solve it?

Comment: Since it's a monster query, can you tell us exactly where the exception is thrown? Can you provide a failing testcase?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: The exception is thrown once I access serviceOrders.Count. Regarding a testcase I'm not sure. It's way over 50 lines.

Comment: how are you managing sessionscopes?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: What do you mean?

Comment: @the_drow: where/how do you do `new SessionScope()` ? Or do you not manage session scopes explicitly?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: I have a session scope above the linq query and another one when I call ActiveRecordMediator's FindAll()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using lazy loading, place all code that accesses lazily loaded relations within a **single** SessionScope. Otherwise you'll get exceptions (unless you manually reattach entities to the new session which is generally troublesome).

Another option is to eagerly fetch everything you need (as opposed to using lazy loading).

Comment: @the_drow: unless you can provide a failing testcase, there is nothing more we can do.

Comment: That linq query was executed out of scope due to it's deferred nature. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a copy of a post I made to the NHUsers group ([Link to the discussion, which discusses several other approaches as well](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/dfe5e3055e8dcc78/c71fa79fb14afff1?lnk=gst&q=tbushell#c71fa79fb14afff1))

I know you have a console app, and my app is WinForms, but the same approach should work for you as well.  It's not ideal, but so far, it's working for me.

======================================================

Session management when using NHibernate, lazy loading, and WinForms
seems to be something many people struggle with - I know I did!

Adding WinForms databinding to the mix is an additional complication
in my project, which has a single main form centered around a third
party grid control.  The grid is databound to my object model, via the
IBindingList interface.

After quite a bit of struggle and hair pulling, the approach that
*seems* to be working is to have a MainSession for the main form that
is kept open most of the time.  This means that whenever the users
navigate through the data with the grid, there's an open session to
handle the lazy loads of data from the database.

For other operations (updates, deletes, etc), I disconnect the main
session, create a new, throwaway session just for that operation, and
then reconnect the main session.

This works, and if it helps somebody else, great.  However, I don't
fully trust it, and it seems every time I add a new capability (delete
was the most recent one), it breaks and has to be tweaked again.  If
anyone has a better suggestion, I'd love to hear it.

Conversely, if it's OK, I'd like to know that too - I'll sleep better
from now on.

Anyway, here's some code excerpted from my project to illustrate the
approach.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// NHibernate session factory used by the application
    /// </summary>
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

   /// <summary>
    /// NHibernate session used by MainForm. Kept open most of the time to facilitate
    /// lazy loading of data.  Disconnected and Reconnected when app writes
    /// new data to database
    /// </summary>
    private static ISession _mainSession;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the main database session, creating it if necessary
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static ISession GetMainSession()
    {
        if (_sessionFactory == null)
        {
            CreateSqliteSessionFactory();
        }

        if (_mainSession == null)
        {
            _mainSession = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        return _mainSession;
    }

    private static void DisconnectMainSession()
    {
        GetMainSession().Disconnect();
    }

    private static void ReconnectMainSession()
    {
        GetMainSession().Reconnect();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save measurement to DB. Does not check for duplicates
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="measurement"></param>
    public static void SaveMeasurement(object measurement)
    {
        DisconnectMainSession();

        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                session.Save(measurement);

                transaction.Commit();

                session.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();

                throw new ApplicationException(
                    "\r\n    SaveMeasurement exception:\r\n\r\n", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                ReconnectMainSession();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: a static ISession is almost always a **bad** idea.

Comment: @Mauricio - I've also heard that keeping a session open for a long time is a bad idea - hence my caveats.  The problem is, I've asked this question more than once on both SO and NHUsers, and never got an answer that met my requirements i.e. WinForms databinding and lazy loading. If you've used a better approach, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: the OP has a console app, not a WinForms app. If you have questions about NHibernate+WinForms, I recommend posting a new question.

Comment: @Mauricio - to repeat what I said in my comment - I've already asked the question - here's the SO link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567677/nhibernate-databinding-to-datagridview-lazy-loading-and-session-managment-ne.  But that was some time ago - maybe you or someone else has a better answer now.  Please read it carefully - the key point is that I am using WinForms databinding.