# Tests with constraint checking errors not caught when using AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests (rollback)

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, integration-testing, spring.net, check-constraints

The majority of my integration tests use spring's `AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests` to do a rollback instead of commiting to the database.  This works well normally but because foreign key constraints are not applied until the commit stage there's a hole in my testing strategy.

How can I improve my tests?

I want to avoid commiting if possible as this causes tests to take much longer to run (when there are many)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you don't want to commit to the database e.g. flush the session, but performance might be acceptable when using an in-memory sqlite database for this purpose.

I've done unit tests using NHibernate (with Fluent NHibernate) and an in-memory sql-lite database ([how to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189280/problem-using-sqlite-memory-with-nhibernate)); this works quite fast as long as you only create the relevant parts of your database instead of the complete schema.

You can easily extend the `AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests` class to flush to the db, see the [spring.net docs 22.2.10](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-integration-testing) or [this thread on the spring.net forum](http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=5246), so you should be able to get this working quickly for your test suite.

Comment: Thanks, we flush the DB in our override of the abstract spriing class